# Getting UmbrellaException when trying to select tab in a TabPanel

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, amcharts

I'm trying to drow some charts using AmCharts in a GWT project.
I use this code

```
public native void paille(int i) /*-{
        var params = {
            bgcolor : "#FFFFFF"
        };

        var flashVars = {
            path : "amcharts/flash/",
            settings_file : "sampleData/pie_settings.xml",
            data_file : "sampleData/pie_data.xml"
        };

        $wnd.swfobject.embedSWF("amcharts/flash/ampie.swf", "page_"+i, 600,
                400, "7.0.0", "amcharts/flash/expressInstall.swf",
                flashVars, params);
    }-*/;
```

The chart appeares but when I try to use the TabPanel tabs, I get the UmbrellaException.
Have you any solution for that?

Comment: "UmbrellaException" is a wrapper for all types of exceptions. The stack trace should show the root exception. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd thank everybody for answers. I found the root problem that I want to share.
I was using this code to set the id of DOM:

```
DOM.setElementAttribute(tabPanel.getWidget(0).getElement(), "id", "id_0");
```

I shouldn't do that, I should create add the id to a flowPanel like this code

```
flowpanel = new FlowPanel();
HTML w = new HTML();
flowpanel.add(w);
tabPanel.add(flowpanel, "titre 0");
DOM.setElementAttribute(w.getElement(), "id", "id_0");
```

I set resolved